# JUPYTER AND CONDA FOR R

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter

I want to use R in Jupyter in windows 7. I have installed anaconda and tried to install "R Essentials" following the directions given in [this link](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r). But I am getting  "SSL verification error, package not found error" as shown in the screenshot. [image]. I have been using R in Jupyter in windows 8,10 and Mac. I am not sure why it is failing in windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set conda to not verify following [this](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/R--3uLp6pi8) answer as shown below and everything worked fine.

```
       conda config --set ssl_verify false
       conda update requests
       conda install -c r r-essentials
```